# How to compare and restart same many Services on many Computers with simple interface

Tags: user-interface, powershell, service

i need to compare status of many services and each dependancy on many remote computer for restart it if needed.

but the output of get-service is poor in CLI

Comment: same problem for Process

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe get-service with Out-GridView, get-service accept a list of computerName.

```
get-service -computerName PC1,PC2 | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple | Restart-Service -force -passthru
```

the function Out-gridView provide a very good user interface.

```
function restartRmService {
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
            [Alias("CN")]
                [string[]]$ComputerName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
            [Alias("CN")]
                [string[]]$serviceName
    ) 
    $Restart = @()

    if ($serviceName) {
        $Restart = Get-Service -ComputerName ($ComputerName | select-Object -unique) -name $serviceName | select *
    }
    else {
        $Restart = Get-Service -ComputerName ($ComputerName | select-Object -unique) | select MachineName, ServiceName, Status, DisplayName, DependentServices, ServicesDependedOn | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple -Title 'Selectionner les Services a Redemarer, puis valider'
    }

    $Restart | %{
        $status = (Get-Service -ComputerName $_.MachineName -ServiceName $_.ServiceName | Restart-Service -force -passthru | select *).status
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use same code for Restart-Process with litle change : replace *Get-Service* by *Get-Process* and replace *Restart-Service* by *Stop-Process*